# how do i print an element of an associative array when i dont know the key name

Tags: php, arrays

this array is generated and i want to be able to somehow grab the parent key without knowing the name, since i wont.
so the value i want is each array groups parent which would be zbench1, zbench2, .. and so on.

this array is already attached to a variable and i tried printing $myelements[0] but it gives an offset error.

```
Array
(
    [zbench] => Array
        (
            [0] => editor-style.css
            [1] => images
            [2] => pagenavi-css.css
            [3] => screenshot.png
            [4] => style.css
        )

    [zbench1] => Array
        (
            [0] => editor-style.css
            [1] => images
            [2] => pagenavi-css.css
            [3] => screenshot.png
            [4] => style.css
        )

    [zbench2] => Array
        (
            [0] => editor-style.css
            [1] => images
            [2] => pagenavi-css.css
            [3] => screenshot.png
            [4] => style.css
        )

    [zbench3] => Array
        (
            [0] => editor-style.css
            [1] => images
            [2] => pagenavi-css.css
            [3] => screenshot.png
            [4] => style.css
        )

)
```

Comment: `array_keys()` will return all the array keys

Comment: array_keys() just prints out array i also tried array_keys(array_keys($myvar));

Comment: @SarmenB. Why would you try that?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the values with [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array as $key=>$value)
```

Or, if you have the key in a variable but don't *a priori* know what it is:

```
$array[$variable_holding_key]
```

Or if you just want to know what the keys are, but not necessarily do anything with them (all):

```
array_keys($array)
```

Answer (score 0):

By definition, the inner arrays are only reachable via keys in the containing array - you have to know which parent key to use to access the appropriate child array. Is there a difference between each of those child arrays, other than having a slightly different parent key?

You can get all the keys in an array via `array_keys()`, which returns the keys as values in another array. Or you can use `foreach($your_array as $key => $val)` to iterate over each element in the array and get its associated key at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

1. `current()` may work, it returns what the cursor is pointing to.
2. `$element[key($element)]`
3. `array_shift`, but this removes the last item.